# ANTLR mismatched input ' ' expecting

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlrworks

I'm making this grammar so that i can recognize streets, post cods, etc, it only gives that error, but i can't solve it.

```
grammar LabeledExpr;

/** The start rule; begin parsing here. */ 
exp: Inicio parte1 parte2 parte4 NL exp 
| Inicio parte6 parte2 parte7 NL exp
|fim;

fim: /*vazio*/;
parte1: Id_Env Str Rua;
parte2: Virg Num parte3|/*vazio*/;
parte3: Andar|/*vazio*/;
parte4:Cod_Postal Str parte5;
parte5: Str |/*vazio*/;
parte6: Cod_Postal Id_Env Rua;
parte7:Str Str parte5;

Space  : (' '|'\t')+ { skip(); }; 
Inicio : '#ID#';
Id_Env: [1-9]Nu?Nu?Nu?|'0';
Rua : '\"'('Rua'|'Av.'|'Trav.')Letra'\"';
Str : '\"'Letra'\"';
Letra: [A-Za-z ]+;
XXXX : [1-9]YYY;
YYY : Nu Nu Nu;
Andar: Num | 'R/C' | 'cave';
Cod_Postal: XXXX('-'YYY)?;
Num: [1-9]Nu*;
Nu: [0-9];
Virg:',';
NL : [\r\n]+;
Ponto: . ;
```

The error is:

```
line 1:38 mismatched input '123' expecting Num
line 2:35 mismatched input '3' expecting Num
line 3:55 mismatched input '9876' expecting Num
line 4:39 mismatched input '2623' expecting Num
```

Does anyone understands it?

Answer (score 0):

Id_Env matches 123  as it is before Num.
Ter

Comment: Sorry that I interrupt, but could you take a look at this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341922/antlr-throws-antlr-runtime-noviablealtexception-in-c-sharp-but-not-in-java-co

Answer (score 0):

You should make some of your lexer rules parser rules instead. Like Ter already pointed out, you have some lexer rules that can match the same input. This is resolved as "first wins", i.e. the topmost wins.

I'd also make `Lettra` a fragment since otherwise it will match things like R/C' or 'cave'.

Also note that `Ponto` matches any single character. Although I'm not proficient in your mother language, it sounds to me like `Ponto` should only match the point, so you have to write `'.'` instead of `.`.